# How do I add a blank column in Power Query Editor where I can input data in on the excel worksheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, power-query

When I add a blank column with values "null (Number from Notes)" in power query editor to my existing data and load it to the worksheet, I'll type some data into the blank column while in the worksheet. However, after I refresh the query, my data is overwritten and my column is blank again.

[image]

How can I stop data from being overwritten when I refresh?

I assume the problem is with the value I originally selected in power query editor.

Comment: I found a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56955256/inserting-comments-column-next-to-power-query-table) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Search for "Power Query self-referring tables"